# Sed Special Character

Tags: sed

I'm trying to replace :

```
#/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
```

With :

```
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO';
```

Here is my sed command which doesn't work...

```
sed 's|#/\*\!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE\, SQL_MODE=`NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO` \*/;|SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE\, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'\;|' file.sql > filenew.sql
```

I guess my problem is the caracter ' but i can't find the solution
Can you help me !

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To bypass the problem of using single quotes inside the `sed` command, surround it between double quotes:

```
sed "s|#/\*\!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE\, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' \*/;|SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE\, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'\;|" file.sql > filenew.sql
```

It yields:

```
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO';
```